# Correspondence between ODE and difference equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

In [Wikipedia about difference equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Theorem), there is some description about correspondence between ODE and difference equation:

> If you consider the Taylor series of
>   the solution to a linear differential
>   equation:$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (x-a)^n$$ you
>   see that the coefficients of the
>   series are given by the nth derivative
>   of $f(x)$ evaluated at the point $a$. The
>   differential equation provides a
>   linear difference equation relating
>   these coefficients.
>
> The rule of thumb (for equations in
>   which the polynomial multiplying the
>   first term is non-zero at zero) is
>   that:$$ y^{[k]} \to f[n+k]$$and more
>   generally $$x^m*y^{[k]} \to n(n-1)(n-m+1)f[n+k-m]$$
>
> Example: The recurrence relationship
>   for the Taylor series coefficients of
>   the equation: $$(x^2 + 3x -4)y^{[3]} -(3x+1)y^{[2]} + 2y = 0\,$$ is given by$$n(n-1)f[n+1] + 3nf[n+2] -4f[n+3] -3nf[n+1] -f[n+2]+ 2f[n] = 0\, $$ or $$-4f[n+3] +2nf[n+2] + n(n-4)f[n+1]  +2f[n] = 0.\,$$

My questions are:

1. I was wondering what the rationale
   behind this conversion from an ODE to
   a difference equation is? Although
   having tried to read it several
   times, I was not able to understand
   it.
2. In reverse direction, can a
   difference equation be converted to
   an ODE using this correspondence?
   How to?
3. Is the conversion of an ODE into a
   difference equation in numerical
   methods for solving an ODE related
   to the correspondence between the
   two mentioned above?
4. > This equivalence can be used to
   >   quickly solve for the recurrence
   >   relationship for the coefficients in
   >   the power series solution of a linear
   >   differential equation.
   >
   > Problems generally solved using the
   >   power series solution method taught in
   >   normal differential equation classes
   >   can be solved in a much easier way.

   I was wondering how exactly the
   correspondence can make solving an
   ODE or a difference equation easier?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All that's going on here is that when you differentiate a Taylor series expansion

$$f(x) = f^{(0)}(a) + \frac{f^{(1)}(a)}{1!} (x - a)^1 + \frac{f^{(2)}(a)}{2!} (x - a)^2 + ...$$

you get the Taylor series expansion

$$f'(x) = f^{(1)}(a) + \frac{f^{(2)}(a)}{1!} (x - a)^1 + \frac{f^{(3)}(a)}{2!} (x - a)^2 + ....$$

In other words, what you've done is precisely shifted the Taylor coefficients one to the left. That's all the Wikipedia article is saying.

I disagree that this makes ODEs any easier to solve, though. ODEs were *already* this easy to solve, you just weren't taught the right language for seeing this.

Comment: In fact, when the Taylor expansion exists and is convergent (so the function is locally real analytic), this also gives easy solutions to **partial** differential equations. This basic machinery in the PDE case is called the Cauchy-Kovalevsky theorem.

Comment: This is the *Principle of Conservation of Difficulty* at work, against which we are in general defenseless! :)